# Anisotropy terms in the free energy functional of a magnetic system (single ion term and compass term)

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

To study a skyrmion system, I study the continuum free energy functional \begin{equation}
    F[\vec{m}] = \int d^2 r \mathcal{F}(\vec{m})
\end{equation}
The anisotropy term is:\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{F}_{aniso} = (A_c/2)[(\partial_xm^y)^2 + (\partial_ym^x)^2] - A_c[(m^x)^2 + (m^y)^2] + A_s(m^z)^2
\end{equation}

Here $A_c$ is called the compass term and $A_s$ is called the single ion term. What do the "compass term" and the "single ion term" physically mean?

Answer (score 0):

Single-ion interaction means you prefer lower (in absolute value) local magnetization in the $z$-direction.

Compass (anisotropy) term are when a 3d magnetization is suppressed into 2d. Think of a Heisenberg like interaction, $J\vec{S}_i\cdot\vec{S}_j$ , in which all three components of the spin contribute the same amount, in a compass interaction you suppress the third component and get an XX like interaction, $J_c(S_i^x S_j^x + S_i^y S_j^y)$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the single ion term? What do you mean by preferring higher local magnetization?

Comment: Sorry, you made me realize my typo. Edited my answer. The $A_s$ term penalizes the energy functional when the (local) $m_z$ is high. While the $A_c$ term favors in plane magnetization, see the second term you had: - $-A_c[(m^x)^2+(m^y)^2]$.